# angular - Show or Hide button on a div mouseover

Tags: angular, hide, show, onmouseover

I have a small angular project that displays list of cars after preforming a search action in the DB. I want to create a situation in which whenever a user is going with the mouse over the div (`<div class="about">`) the button (`<button class="call">`) is being displayed and whenever the user leave the area of the div the same button hides.

Any idea how can I do this? If this is possible, how can I do something similar when user is using a mobile device?

The list is dynamically created from a search in the db so I can't use CSS id to show or hide it with CSS.

```js
<a class="result_row_item" *ngFor="let item of cars; let i = index">
    <div class="about">
        <div class="mark">
            <b>{{item.manufacturerName}}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="descr">
            <span class="safety_mark">safety mark -<b> {{item.safetyMark}}  </b></span>
            <span class="zaro_to">0-100 <b> {{item.zeroTo100}} </b></span>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_nav">
            <button class="call" (click)='triggerModalInfo(item.submodelId)'>more info</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img_container" (click)='triggerModal(item.submodelId)' [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ this.env.baseCarsUrl + '/images/cars/'+(item.modelThumbnail | lowercase)+ '/main.jpg'+')'}">
    </div>
    <div class="num">{{i+1}}</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
hideElement = true;
```

```html
<div class="box" 
  (mouseover)="hideElement = false"
  (mouseleave)="hideElement = true"
  >
    <button [hidden]="hideElement">more info</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

there is an event called **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** in angular you can try like this

so you can try like this

HTML:

```
  <a class="result_row_item" *ngFor="let item of cars; let i = index">
<div class="about" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter('true') (mouseleave)="mouseLeave('false')">
    <div class="mark">
        <b>{{item.manufacturerName}}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="descr">
        <span class="safety_mark">safety mark -<b> {{item.safetyMark}}  </b></span>
        <span class="zaro_to">0-100 <b> {{item.zeroTo100}} </b></span>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_nav" *ngIf="isDisplay">
        <button class="call" (click)='triggerModalInfo(item.submodelId)'>more info</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="img_container" (click)='triggerModal(item.submodelId)' [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ this.env.baseCarsUrl + '/images/cars/'+(item.modelThumbnail | lowercase)+ '/main.jpg'+')'}">
</div>
<div class="num">{{i+1}}</div>
```

Component:

```
   export class component1Component{
     mouseEnter(data : any){
        this.isDisplay= data;
     }

     mouseLeave(data : any){
        this.isDisplay = data;
     }
   }
```

I hope it helps you out

Comment: thank you for that. 
due to the fact that i have a list of cars that create a list of elements, i created an array of boolean values and initiated them to false uppon start, and in mouse enter and mouse leave i added the index of the element. somthing like this: 
 <div class="about"  (mouseenter)="mouseEnter('true',i)" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave('false',i)">.

Component:

  public showElement: Array<Boolean>=[];
  


  mouseEnter(data: any, i: any) {
      this.showElement[i] = true;
  }

  mouseLeave(data: any, i: any) {
      this.showElement[i] = false;
  }

Comment: Ohh okay got it. if my answer helped you it would be great if you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using mouse events,

**In your template,**

```
<a class="result_row_item" *ngFor="let item of cars; let i = index">
    <div class="about" (mouseenter)="showElement=!showElement" (mouseleave)="showElement=!showElement">
        <div class="mark">
            <b>{{item.manufacturerName}}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="descr">
            <span class="safety_mark">safety mark -<b> {{item.safetyMark}}  </b></span>
            <span class="zaro_to">0-100 <b> {{item.zeroTo100}} </b></span>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_nav" *ngIf="showElement">
            <button class="call" (click)='triggerModalInfo(item.submodelId)'>more info</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img_container" (click)='triggerModal(item.submodelId)' [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ this.env.baseCarsUrl + '/images/cars/'+(item.modelThumbnail | lowercase)+ '/main.jpg'+')'}">
    </div>
    <div class="num">{{i+1}}</div>
</a>
```

**In your component,**

```
showElement: boolean = true;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="bottom_nav" [hidden]="!showElement">
    <button class="call" (click)='triggerModalInfo(item.submodelId)'>more info</button>
</div>
```

It worked for me in Angular 8.